# Android Problem loading widget - without errors in the logcat

Tags: java, android, canvas, widget, android-widget

I created an analog clock widget in java, and for some reason I get "Problem loading widget" all the time, the only things I get from the logcat when I try to place the widget are:

```
2020-11-18 19:19:13.162 9482-9482/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-11-18 19:19:13.162 9482-9482/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-11-18 19:19:13.166 9482-9482/? I/ckcustomizatio: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-11-18 19:19:13.182 9482-9482/? E/ckcustomizatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-11-18 19:19:13.196 9482-9482/com.l_es.analogclockcustomization D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
2020-11-18 19:19:13.196 9482-9482/com.l_es.analogclockcustomization D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put
```

and the widget is only a black square with "Problem loading widget" on it.

here is the widget class:

```
public class MainWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static RemoteViews views;
    //preferences
    private static SharedPreferences custClockPrefs;
    //number of possible designs
    private static int numClocks;
    //IDs of Analog Clock elements
    static int[] clockDesigns;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        numClocks = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.num_clocks);
        clockDesigns = new int[numClocks];
        for(int d = 0; d < numClocks; d++){
            clockDesigns[d] = context.getResources().getIdentifier
                    ("AnalogClock"+d, "id", context.getPackageName());
        }
        //find out the action
        String action = intent.getAction();
        //is it time to update
        if(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.clock_widget_layout);

            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget
                    (intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS), views);

            custClockPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("CustomClockPrefs", 0);
            int chosenDesign = custClockPrefs.getInt("clockdesign", 0);
            if(chosenDesign >= 0){
                for(int d = 0; d < numClocks; d++){
                    if(d != chosenDesign)
                        views.setViewVisibility(clockDesigns[d], View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                views.setViewVisibility(clockDesigns[chosenDesign], View.VISIBLE);
            }

            Intent choiceIntent = new Intent(context, ClockChoice.class);
            PendingIntent clickPendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                    (context, 0, choiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.custom_clock_widget, clickPendIntent);

        }
    }

}
```

here is the draw function I use in order to draw the clock:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    final float w = (float) getWidth() / 2;
    final float h = (float) getHeight() / 2;

    final int saveCount = canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(w, h);
    final float scale = Math.min((float) w / mDial.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            (float) h / mDial.getIntrinsicHeight());
    if (scale < 1f) {
        canvas.scale(scale, scale, 0f, 0f);
    }
    mDial.draw(canvas);

    final float hourAngle = mTime.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 30f;
    canvas.rotate(hourAngle, 0f, 0f);
    mHourHand.draw(canvas);

    final float minuteAngle = mTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 6f;
    canvas.rotate(minuteAngle - hourAngle, 0f, 0f);
    mMinuteHand.draw(canvas);

    if (mEnableSeconds) {
        final float secondAngle = mTime.get(Calendar.SECOND) * 6f;
        canvas.rotate(secondAngle - minuteAngle, 0f, 0f);
        mSecondHand.draw(canvas);
    }
    canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
}
```

Here is my layout file of the widget, keep in mind that I set at every time 2 out of the 3 to be with visibility of "gone":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/custom_clock_widget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/clock_margin"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.l_es.analogclockcustomization.AnalogClockDesign
        android:id="@+id/AnalogClock0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:showSecondHand="false"
        app:dial="@drawable/clock_dial_2"
        app:hour="@drawable/clock_hour_hand_2"
        app:minute="@drawable/clock_minute_hand_2"/>

    <com.l_es.analogclockcustomization.AnalogClockDesign
        android:id="@+id/AnalogClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:showSecondHand="false"
        app:dial="@drawable/clock_dial_3"
        app:hour="@drawable/clock_hour_hand_3"
        app:minute="@drawable/clock_minute_hand_3"/>

    <com.l_es.analogclockcustomization.AnalogClockDesign
        android:id="@+id/AnalogClock2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:showSecondHand="false"
        app:dial="@drawable/clock_dial_4"
        app:hour="@drawable/clock_hour_hand_4"
        app:minute="@drawable/clock_minute_hand_4"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

clock_widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/clock_widget_layout"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Please post the layout file

Comment: I added the widget layout file, please look, thank you

Comment: Have you overrided `onUpdate()` on `MainWidget`?

Comment: as you can see in the code, I didn't, I posted the entire class of it, there are only 
    variables and `onReceive`

Comment: From where is `onReceive()` (`MainWidget`) called?

Comment: it's a function that gets called automatically
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224956/discussion-between-vishnu-and-lidor-eliyahu-shelef).

Comment: Is it so? Isn't `onUpdate()` called automatically?

Comment: I didn't override the onUpdate method, I use the onReceive

Comment: Oh! You are using `<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" /> intent-filter`. Right?

Comment: yes, in the manifest, and also there's this one: 

`<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/clock_widget" />`

Comment: Yeah. Back to the point... I have also got this error. It was due to unsupported layout components. I can't figure out the reason here...

Comment: Hi, can you just show me clock_widget.xml?

Comment: I added the clock_widget.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check elements you used in the view in a Widget..

[Documentation link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:

- FrameLayout
- LinearLayout
- RelativeLayout
- GridLayout

And the following widget classes:

1. AnalogClock
2. Button
3. Chronometer
4. ImageButton
5. ImageView
6. ProgressBar
7. TextView
8. ViewFlipper
9. ListView
10. GridView
11. StackView
12. AdapterViewFlipper

Using forbidden elements causes this very

Problem Loading Widget
message, without saying where did it happen.

Comment: I used only the allowed layouts and classes on the widget layout as you can see in the cod eI posted

Comment: com.l_es.analogclockcustomization.AnalogClockDesign This is a layout not present in above list but in your clock_widget_layout.xml

Comment: its instead of the AnalogClock you specify in your list, b/c the AnalogClock is deprecated I took the origin code and used it instead of the android library

Comment: You have to use **exactly** those classes - you can't create a copy of `AnalogClock` that works with `RemoteViews`.

Comment: the AnalogClock is deprecated, so how can I use it?
I used the exact same code 1 to 1 from the android developer site